# Pulled Toilet . Water Damage Assessment Request

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, subfloor, water-damage

I bought a 30 year old house and noticed that the toilet was rocking. Mounting screws pulled right out (see pic).

I pulled the toilet. The flange was completely rusted through and the wax was completely dried out (see pic). The pipe looks fine.

The wood is not wet, but I haven't used this toilet in a couple months. The wood does not flake off or compress when pressed on.

Is it worth cutting the subfloor and assessing the damage underneath?

What is the worst case? If wood is fine is there anything I need to do to refurb it? I am planning on laying tile down.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That seems like a long term leak.  Just for peace of mind I would check out the floor supports near there.  Might have just leaked onto a dirt floor and supports are perfect, or leaked onto supports and they need fixing.

Comment: Can you get at the crawlspace underneath there? Doesn't look awful from the top though. Dows the wood feel at all soft or spongy? FWIW I've seen much worse - I bought a little cottage a few years ago where the only thing preventing the toilet from falling through the floor was the cast-iron drain beneath it ... :P

Comment: That wood doesn't look fine from here. When you get to the tiling stage, just cut a big chunk out, assess thoroughly, and put a new chunk down.

Comment: The screws pulled right out *of what* ?!?! The holes that aren't there? This is Start Over.

Answer (score 0):

Check the wood underneath. Normally the wood subfloor will degrade first, but checking everything is advised.

After any wood is repaired, if needed, install a [twist and set toilet flange](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-4-in-PVC-Twist-N-Set-Open-Toilet-Flange-436512/100062268?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-CON-NA-All_Cons&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-CON-NA-All_Cons-71700000116949521-58700008649202607-92700079210234085&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAqY6tBhAtEiwAHeRopRIZldBBF7v2Vi-zVWC6RZEUw8HQ30SH44dBcEJBniQLVL-xYzv1PhoCcTQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).  (3 and 4 inch sizes are available.)

The flange gives a better base to attach the toilet, and can be screwed to the subfloor.  The height will make the flange very close to level after you add your floor tile on top.